# Sun Grid Engine Dynamic resource allocation

Tags: gridengine

My cluster is running Sun's Grid Engine version "GE 6.2u5 $Date: 2009/12/01 12:24:06 $". I'd like to submit a single job to the queue which is defined by a bash script containing a number of commands. Most of the commands in this script can only make use of 1 CPU. However, one single command can make use of N CPUs. Is it possible to somehow request more processors for just this one single command in my script?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocating resources like this is impossible with SGE.
The proper way to handle this situation is to split the script defining the job into three pieces: A,B,C where
A=script with commands needing onlu 1 cpu
B=script with command needing N CPUs
C=script with commans needing only 1 cpu

Then the trick is to submit these three scripts as three different jobs with the final two being dependent on the previous two being completed.